# How to optimize a Liferay portal with web services?

Tags: web-services, liferay

I created a Liferay 6.2 portal. Their portlets make calls to an external Web Services (ie feeds, weather).

In order to optimize the portal performance, I cannot make calls at client level (I want them server-side). In other words, when the portal starts, the answer to Web Service request must be initially made by server, to be available when accessing to portal.

I searched Liferay EhCache for this situations, but I didn´t understand the practice Applications. Is this procedure the best way?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest liferay has quite poor performance. On our high loaded projects we made a lot of things to improve it.

But on the start point will be enough to have a cache.

You can do it like:

ehache.xml:

```
<cache name="weatherCache" eternal="false"
       maxElementsInMemory="1000" overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
       diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
```

WeatherServiceImpl :

```
@Service
public class WeatherServiceImpl implements WeatherService, CacheKeyGenerator<Serializable> {
   ...


  @Override
  @Cacheable(cacheName = "weatherCache", keyGenerator = @KeyGenerator(name = "xxx.yyy.WeatherServiceImpl"))
  public WeatherResult getWeatherResult(...){
  }
   ...

  @Override
  public Serializable generateKey(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) {
   //methodInvocation.getArguments()[0]
   ....
  }

  @Override
  public Serializable generateKey(Object... objects) {
    ....
  }
  ...

}
```

Comment: Olaf and Maksym, thanks for the answers. The Web services from widgets (eg http://www.accuweather.com) can also be cached? If not, do you know any Web Service that has this behaviour?

Comment: You can and should cache not frequently changeable data from any web services and particularly from accuweather.com.

Comment: The problem is this kind of Web Service do not use the class which implements the service (the answer is obtained in portlet view), i.e., in JSP, the service call is made like:

<a class="aw-widget-legal" href="http://www.accuweather.com/pt/pt/coimbra/272818/weather-forecast/272818"></a>
<div class="aw-widget-current" data-locationkey="" data-uid="awcc1415207777127" data-unit="c" data-useip="true" id="awcc1415207777127"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://oap.accuweather.com/launch.js"></script>

In this case, there is another way to save data caching?

Answer (score 0):

For feeds and weather it makes sense to cache them - they typically don't change every now and then. You can also display your portlets asynchronously. Look up "ajaxable" and "render-weight" in [liferay-portlet.xml](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd.html#render-weight) (or its DTD, which is well documented)

Maksym has already given some code on how to implement this - Naturally I don't necessarily agree with him on the performance assumptions. If you call an external webservice and it takes 1 second for the answer, you can easily end up with bad performance. However, that's not a property of Liferay then, but of your integration of that external service.

Comment: Sorry, probably my bad of pointing it, I meant in general about liferay performance, not related to web services.

Comment: well, even there it depends and you can get good performance and great scaling out of Liferay. What does it depend on? Infrastructure, customizations, applications used etc. - but let's not get into a fight in these comments. I just couldn't let it stand like this but it's ok if we agree to disagree